# OpenAI GPT-4 API error: "The model: gpt-4 does not exist"

Tags: openai-api, php-curl, gpt-4

I have code as below, it works perfect with model `gpt-3.5-turbo` but not with `gpt-4`:

```
$your_prompt = "Prompt...."

// GPT-4 API call
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer [API-KEY]';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = json_encode(array('model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo', 
                          'messages' => array(
                                            array('role' => 'system', 'content' => 'Your system message here'), 
                                            array('role' => 'user', 'content' => $your_prompt))));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result."<br>";

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl Error:' . curl_error($ch) . "\n<br>";
} else {
    echo "API call successful.\n<br>";
    echo "API response: \n<br>";
    print_r(json_decode($result, true));
    echo "\n";
}
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($result, true);
$text = $response['choices'][0]['message']['content'];

echo "OutputGPT" . $text . "\n<br>";
```

When I'm using `gpt-4` I get:

```
Processing prompt: what is a wether today in Warsaw Poland
{ "error": { "message": "The model: `gpt-4` does not exist", "type": "invalid_request_error", "param": null, "code": "model_not_found" } }
API call successful.
API response:
Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => The model: `gpt-4` does not exist [type] => invalid_request_error [param] => [code] => model_not_found ) ) OutputGPT
```

I have tried also with others models like `gpt-3.5-turbo-0613` and it works to, but not for `gpt-4` as well as for `gpt-4-0613`. Nevertheless it should based on https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-4

Answer (score 7):

**Since July 6, 2023, the GPT-4 8k models have been accessible through the API to those users who have made a successful payment of $1 or more through the OpenAI developer platform. Generate a new API key if your old one was generated before the payment.**

Take a look at the official OpenAI documentation.

For the [GPT-4](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-4) models, you can see the following notice:

[image: Screenshot 1]

While for the [GPT-3.5](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5) models, there's no such notice:

[image: Screenshot 2]

As stated in the official [OpenAI article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4):

> If you've made a successful payment of $1 or more, you'll be able to
> access the GPT-4 8k API.

Additional notes:

- **Can I get instant access to GPT-4 8k models via API even if I haven't spent at least $1 in the past?** Yes, if your account was created after August 18, 2023, and you purchase $0.50 worth or more of [pre-paid credits](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/8264644-what-is-prepaid-billing).
- **Why don't I get access to the GPT-4 8k models via API even though I paid $20 for my ChatGPT Plus subscription?** OpenAI API usage is *not* included in the ChatGPT Plus subscription.

Comment: I made my first payment on July first, and I still cannot use GPT-4.

Comment: @crlb Try to create a new API key and use the new one. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Tried that, did not work.

Comment: I just set up my paid account, and added my card. Now, bill would be deducted at the end of the month. How to make a payment of 1$ before that?

Comment: @RaghavArora I don't think you can "speed up" the billing process (read the [article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6640792-when-can-i-expect-to-receive-my-openai-api-invoice) on that matter).

Comment: I made more then one payment, but gpt-4-32k is not available for me

Comment: @YuriyZaletskyy Read my answer carefully again: *We are not currently granting access to the GPT-4 32k API at this time, but it will be made available at a later date.*  Only the GPT-4 8k models (i.e., `gpt-4` and `gpt-4-0613`) are accessible via the API as of today.

Comment: Is there a way to credit some money? I am up to $0.42 and would need to create a loop constantly calling the API just to get above $1.

Comment: @MadMac If that's your goal, I suggest you use [DALL·E](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/dall-e). Why? 1) It's the most expensive OpenAI model. 2) Using the loop will very possibly hit your rate limit sooner or later. 3) Why not play a bit with generative AI? It's fun (at least to me).

Comment: @MadMac [Prepaid billing](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/8264644-what-is-prepaid-billing) is now available.

Comment: @RokBenko was correct. Had to create a new API key after making a payment.

Comment: @rotarydial Thanks for the feedback. I edited my answer and added this piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is necessary to pay at least $5 to use the API Keys with the above mentioned models.

From my experience, an institutional account is not fully functional, even if you create another API Key, it can no longer be used as satisfactorily.